# How to send request to admin for approval of catalog item?

Tags: servicenow

I am facing some issue in service now workflow.Can someone please help me with the issue .Please find the below description of task and issue :

What I am trying do is :

1. Create catalog items.
2. Checkout catalog item.
3. Approver should approve the request.
4. Close the ticket.

Process Followed :

- Logged in service now instance as a system administrator.
- Created two users user1 and user2 with catalog_admin role.
- Created one group name catalog_group and added both users in the     group.
- Added the worlflow in catalog item and set group approver as catalog_group.
- Logged in as a user1 and selected item and placed order.
- Now no state displayed in the incident.When I checked the ticket there are no approver added.
- Logged in as a user2 .

Issue :

User2 is not seeing any incident to approve.Incident created by user1 should be displayed in user2's home page for approval.

[image: Approval -user]

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your "Approval" block? That might clear things up a bit more.

Comment: The only thing I find strange is that you send the approval to the same user named "Catalog_Admin" twice. It would probably make more sense to create a Group called "Catalog_Admins", put user1 and user2 in that group and have the approvals send to that group instead.
Aside from, I would check out the related list called "Approvers" on the Requested Item. That should show the correct names or you could at least see which people are asked to request the item.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Thank you very much.That is the best explanation I got .I will try and inform you the same.Thank you so much .

Comment: @PeterRaeves I have updated my  question.Can you please take a look of process because still I am not able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut feeling tells me that you chose **the wrong table**; That you created the workflow on the "Catalog Item" table instead of the "Requested Item" table. People seem to forget that an Item is a catalog item as long as it is in the catalog, but from the moment it is requested, a copy is stored to the database as a requested item. Therefore the workflow should happen on the requested item, not the catalog item.

---

I recreated what you did and everything works as expected. I will post screenshots below, so you could see what you did differently.

- I logged in as System Administrator.
- Created two users user1 and user2.
- Created a group called "catalog_group" and added both users to the group.
- Added the role of "approver_user" to the group.

As a best practice, you should **add roles to the groups** users are in, instead of the users themselves. This is easier to maintain, as the roles are automatically added to the user when they enter a group or removed when they leave a group.

I gave them the **approver_user** role, instead of the catalog_admin role, because they are approvers and not catalog administrators. Users with the catalog_admin role

> Can manage the Service Catalog application, including catalog categories and items.

That might not be what you want. You can read more about the base system roles, [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/administer/roles/reference/r_BaseSystemRoles.html).

[image]

- Created a new workflow on the Requested Item table.

[image]
[image]

- Created a new Catalog Item with the workflow.

[image]

- Requested the item as System Administrator.

[image]

- Finally, I impersonated both User One and User Two, and you can see that they have the item in their approval list.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I figured out my mistakes and solved all the mistakes now I am able to send request and approve.It was really very helpful answer.